# Kalmanfilter GNSS IMU

Tags: gps, algorithm, filter

I want to make an uncoupled Kalman filter. The input data are GPS and the output of my strapdown Algorithm from the IMU. The Strapdown Algorithm is used to calculate the actual position and velocity from the given daten from an Inertial Navigation System (Inertial measurement unit [received data are from the accelerometer and gyroscope]). The GPS data are given as phi, lambda and h with a time. Do I have to transform them into x,y and z? My Strapdown output is also in phi, lambda and h. How do I know the dimensions of my matrizes? The most important thing to know is: My Strapdown output do not provide a time. Therefore when do I know if I have to use the Strapdown output? Only if there is no data provided by GPS?

Comment: This sounds highly specialized; it is difficult even to determine whether it is on topic here (or on any other SE site). If you would like to increase your chances of getting useful advice from this community, please edit your question to explain what you mean by "strapdown" and "IMU."